# TortoiseSVN not detecting change to SVN repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, detect

we recently had our SVN repository disappear from the server hosting it.  We still haven't figured out how it happened, but we had a semi-recent backup which we were able to use to recover the repository.  We didn't lose any work (everyone had back ups of their most recent changes on their hard drives) but the revision numbers essentially reverted back to older revisions when we started using the old backup of the repository.

The SVN server appears to be corrected now, but I've noticed some issues with tortoiseSVN which I believe were caused by the changes to the SVN server.  On my local machine I was unable to see any revision that occurred after we reverted to the backup SVN.  I was able to fix this by deleting tortoiseSVN and reinstalling the newer version.

Now my colleague is trying to update his SVN trunk and is seeing extremely old versions of files (much older then the backup was).  The svn server has the correct files and others are able to access it, so this appears to be an issue with his client.  He has tried deleting tortoise and reinstalling it but this didn't help.  I suspect that tortoise is somehow storing/detecting (incorrect) information about the SVN server despite the reinstall; but I don't know how this is possible.  Does anyone know how we can force his client to check the SVN server and detect the changes that have occurred?

Comment: Report this problem in Tortoise's bugtracker: http://issues.tortoisesvn.net/

Comment: that bug tracker is not used anymore (see the note at the top of that page). And never, ever just enter a new issue in the issue tracker: always use the mailing list first.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do after such an event (i.e., a backup of the repo is a few revisions behind):

1. export all your working copies of that repositories to a new location
2. delete the working copy
3. check out a new working copy from the backed up repository
4. copy the exported working copy data over the new checked out working copy
5. commit the changes that are showing in your working copy: those are the changes from the missing revisions of the repository

If you're using TortoiseSVN, you also should clear the log cache (settings dialog->saved data->clear)